# Determinant and eigenvalues of an exponential matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

So I have the following exponential matrix.

$$e^{At} = \frac{1}{11}\begin{bmatrix}10+e^{11t} & -1+e^{11t} & -3+3e^{11t}\\-1+e^{11t} & 10+e^{11t} & -3+3e^{11t}\\ -3+3e^{11t} & -3+3e^{11t} & 2+9e^{11t}\end{bmatrix}$$

The determinant of this matrix is $0$, due to one of the eigenvalues being $0$. However, how can I see on the matrix that there is an eigenvalue that is $0$?

Comment: A matrix of the form $e^B$ can never have an eigenvalue of zero, so you must have made a mistake. Note that $e^{-B} e^B = I$, hence invertible, hence no zero eigenvalue.

Comment: There must be an error: I have computed $det(e^{At})=e^{11t}$ ! It cannot have a null eigenvalue and thus its kernel is reduced to $\{0\}$.